# aioMySQL not connecting with python

Tags: python, mysql, aio-mysql

I know this is somewhat of a duplicate, but I've looked in every nook and cranny of the internet and I can't seem to find the solution to this. Basically, I'm trying to connect to a mySQL database via aioMySQL. My Script is far too long to put in, but it was able to connect to an already setup mySQL/phpMyAdmin just fine. When I run it trying to connect to the new db, I get

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<database.createPool() done, defined at /home/blackcoffee/Desktop/Code/She11Sh0ck/dbhandler.py:13> exception=OperationalError(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'X.X.X.X'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blackcoffee/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 486, in _connect
    self._reader, self._writer = await \
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 455, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 52, in open_connection
    transport, _ = await loop.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1017, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1002, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 916, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 485, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 517, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('X.X.X.X', 3306)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blackcoffee/Desktop/Code/She11Sh0ck/dbhandler.py", line 15, in createPool
    self.pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(
  File "/home/blackcoffee/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiomysql/pool.py", line 29, in _create_pool
    await pool._fill_free_pool(False)
  File "/home/blackcoffee/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiomysql/pool.py", line 167, in _fill_free_pool
    conn = await connect(echo=self._echo, loop=self._loop,
  File "/home/blackcoffee/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 75, in _connect
    await conn._connect()
  File "/home/blackcoffee/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 521, in _connect
    raise OperationalError(2003,
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'X.X.X.X'")
```

Looking at some details on my server,

```
mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version      5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         5 min 26 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 4  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 105  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 98  Queries per second avg: 0.012
```

Lastly, I know my root password is correct because I can log in to phpMyAdmin with it with no problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Progress Update: I got it to connect by changing the bind-address to 0.0.0.0, but now it's giving me another error. Here is the code to handle the db as well as the error.

```
import asyncio

import aiomysql

from creds import getdb


# Connect to server
class database:
    def __init__(self):
        print("SQL DB STARTED")

    async def createPool(self, loop):
        dbcreds = getdb()
        self.pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(
            host=dbcreds["host"],
            port=dbcreds["port"],
            user=dbcreds["user"],
            password=dbcreds["password"],
            db=dbcreds["db"],
            loop=loop,
        )

    async def getUserCTFID(self, discordID, guildID):
        sql = "SELECT activectf FROM members where `uuid` = %d and `guildid` = %d" % (
            int(discordID),
            int(guildID),
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                (r) = await cur.fetchone()
                return r[0]
        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def getCTFID(self, name, guildID):
        sql = "SELECT ctfid FROM ctfs where `name` = '{}' and `guildid` = '{}'".format(
            str(name), int(guildID),
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                (r) = await cur.fetchone()
                return r[0]

    async def getCTFName(self, CTFID):
        sql = "SELECT name FROM ctfs where `ctfid` = %d" % (int(CTFID))
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                (r) = await cur.fetchone()
                return r[0]
        # self.pool.close()
        # wait self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def getCTFQuestions(self, CTFID):
        sql = "SELECT name,Solved FROM ctfQuestions where `ctfid` = %d" % (int(CTFID))
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                (r) = await cur.fetchall()
                return r
        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def getValidCTFIDs(self, DiscordID, GuildID):
        sql = "SELECT ctfs.ctfid,ctfs.name FROM members INNER JOIN ctfs ON ctfs.guildid=members.guildid WHERE ctfs.guildid = members.guildid and members.uuid = {} and members.guildid = {}".format(
            int(DiscordID), int(GuildID)
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                (r) = await cur.fetchall()
                return r
        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def updateCTF(self, DiscordID, GuildID, CTFID):
        sql = "UPDATE `members` SET `activectf`={} WHERE uuid={} and guildid={}".format(
            int(CTFID), int(DiscordID), int(GuildID)
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                await conn.commit()
        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def createCTF(self, ctfName, guildID):
        print(ctfName)
        sql = "INSERT INTO ctfs (name, guildid) VALUES ('{}','{}')".format(
            str(ctfName), int(guildID)
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                await conn.commit()

    async def deleteCTF(self, ctfName, guildID):
        print("Goodbye {}".format(ctfName))
        sql = "DELETE FROM `ctfs` WHERE name = '{}' and guildid = '{}'".format(
            str(ctfName), int(guildID)
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                await conn.commit()
            # self.pool.close()
            # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def getGuildByID(self, guildid):
        sql = "SELECT guildid, guildname from guilds where guildid={}".format(
            int(guildid)
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                return await cur.fetchone()

        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def getMember(self, uuid, guildid):
        sql = "SELECT id from members where uuid = {} and guildid={}".format(
            int(uuid), int(guildid)
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                return await cur.fetchone()

        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def addMember(self, uuid, guildid):
        sql = "INSERT INTO members (uuid,guildid, activectf) VALUES ('{}','{}','{}')".format(
            int(uuid), int(guildid), 0
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                await conn.commit()

        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def addGuild(self, guildid, guildname):
        sql = "INSERT INTO guilds (guildid, guildname) VALUES ('{}','{}')".format(
            int(guildid), str(guildname)
        )
        print(sql)
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                await conn.commit()

        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def addQuestion(self, questionName, CTFID):
        sql = "INSERT INTO ctfQuestions (name, ctfid, Solved) VALUES ('{}','{}', '{}')".format(
            str(questionName), int(CTFID), 0
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                await conn.commit()

        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def updateQuestionState(self, questionName, CTFID, state):
        sql = "UPDATE `ctfQuestions` SET `Solved`='{}' WHERE name='{}' and CTFID='{}'".format(
            int(state), str(questionName), int(CTFID)
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                await conn.commit()

        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()

    async def setSolved(self, questionName, CTFID):
        await self.updateQuestionState(questionName, CTFID, 1)

    async def setUnsolved(self, questionName, CTFID):
        await self.updateQuestionState(questionName, CTFID, 0)

    async def delQuestion(self, questionName, CTFID):
        sql = "DELETE FROM `ctfQuestions` WHERE name='{}' and CTFID='{}' ".format(
            str(questionName), int(CTFID)
        )
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(sql)
                await conn.commit()

        # self.pool.close()
        # await self.pool.wait_closed()
```

```
An open stream object is being garbage collected; call "stream.close()" explicitly.
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object Connection._get_server_information at 0x7fedfa7be6c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blackcoffee/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 989, in _get_server_information
    packet = await self._read_packet()
  File "/home/blackcoffee/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 561, in _read_packet
    packet_header = await self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/home/blackcoffee/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 599, in _read_bytes
    except asyncio.streams.IncompleteReadError as e:
AttributeError: module 'asyncio.streams' has no attribute 'IncompleteReadError'
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<database.createPool() running at /home/blackcoffee/Desktop/Code/She11Sh0ck/dbhandler.py:15> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fedf9624ee0>()]>>
```

To be honest, I have no idea what to make of this error

SELECT @@thread_handling; gives:

```
+---------------------------+
| @@thread_handling         |
+---------------------------+
| one-thread-per-connection |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Could you login to your MySQL for Client Command Prompt, SELECT @@thread_handling; and post the results?

Comment: Just added it @WilsonHauck

Comment: Is it possible to support a pool with thread_handling of 'one-thread-per-connection'?  Could you post results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%pool%';  and B) SHOW plugins;

Comment: @BlackCoffee Your SQL queries are prone to SQL injection. Always use parameterized SQL.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like such an idiot. After days and days of searching, the solution was to allow a connection from my own ip.

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to  <user>@<my_ip> IDENTIFIED BY <my_password>;
```